# problem with changing the value of a static variable in its child widget by calling set state method in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, setstate

I have a home screen which inside the homescreen in tab bar view I have returned a chatpage
in this chatpage when the user is doing long press click I want to change the appBar's actions in homeScreen. for doing that I have created a static variable which is named selected inside the homeScreen so I can change the value in my chatpage widget and then if the selected value is true I would have an appbar with actions widget otherwise I wouldn't have an actions.
this is my codes How can I solve this problem. this is homescreen class

```
static bool selected = false;
```

```
TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: [
          const CommunityPage(),
          
          ChatPage(
           // in here I want to change the value of selected variable
            chatModels: widget.chatModels,
          ),
          const StatusPage(),
          const CallsPage(),
        ],
      ),
```

this activity will change the HomeScreen.selected and if it was true or false it whould do this

```
      actions: [
        HomeScreen.selected
            ? Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (_) =>
                        ThemeConsumer(child: ThemeDialog()));
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.palette,
                color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                    ? Colors.grey
                    : Colors.white60,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(FeatherIcons.camera,
                    color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                        ? Colors.grey
                        : Colors.white70)),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                    ? Colors.grey
                    : Colors.white70,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            PopupMenuButton(
                color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                    ? appBarColor
                    : Colors.white,
                icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert,
                    color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                        ? Colors.grey
                        : Colors.white),
                onSelected: (value) {
                  if (value == 0) {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, CreateGroup.routName);
                  }
                },
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      value: 0,
                      child: Text(
                        "New group",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text(
                        "New broadcast",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text(
                        "Linked devices",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text(
                        "Starred messages",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text(
                        "Settings",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ];
                })
          ],
        )
            : Row()
      ],
```

this is my ChatPage codes which inside that it should change the homeScreen.selected value

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/Model/ChatModel.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/Screens/chat/chatScreen.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/constants/colors.dart';

import '../CustomUI/show_image_fullScreen.dart';
import '../Screens/contacts/select_contact.dart';
import '../Screens/home/HomeScreen.dart';
import '../utils/theme_manager.dart';

class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatPage({Key? key, required this.chatModels}) : super(key: key);
  final List<ChatModel> chatModels;
  static List<int> selectedIndexList = [];

  @override
  State<ChatPage> createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  List<Contact>? contacts;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllContacts();
  }


  void getAllContacts() async {
    bool isGranted = await Permission.contacts.isGranted;
    if (!isGranted) {
      isGranted = await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted;
    }
    List myContacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts()).toList();
    setState(() {
      contacts = myContacts.cast<Contact>();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, SelectContact.routName);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.chat, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      body: contacts == null
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: contacts!.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                int randomNumber = Random().nextInt(colors.length);
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onLongPress: () {
                        if (!HomeScreen.selected) {
                          setState(() {
                            HomeScreen.selected = true;
                            ChatPage.selectedIndexList.add(index);
                          });
                        } else {
                          if (ChatPage.selectedIndexList.contains(index)) {
                            setState(() {
                              ChatPage.selectedIndexList.remove(index);
                            });
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              ChatPage.selectedIndexList.add(index);
                            });
                          }
                        }
                        if (ChatPage.selectedIndexList.isEmpty) {
                          setState(() {
                            HomeScreen.selected = false;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        leading: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                return ShowImageFullScreen(
                                  sorceChat: widget.chatModels[0],
                                  image: Image.asset("assets/1.jpg"),
                                  tabBarOptions: false,
                                );
                              }));
                            },
                            child: (contacts![index].avatar == null)
                                ? CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                    radius: 30,
                                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                      "assets/person.svg",
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      width: 38,
                                      height: 38,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                : Stack(
                                    children: [
                                      CircleAvatar(
                                        backgroundColor: colors[randomNumber]
                                            ['color'],
                                        radius: 30,
                                        child: Text(
                                          contacts![index].initials(),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: colors[randomNumber]
                                                          ['mode'] ==
                                                      'light'
                                                  ? Colors.black54
                                                  : Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      HomeScreen.selected &&
                                          ChatPage.selectedIndexList.contains(index)
                                          ? Positioned(
                                              bottom: 0,
                                              right: 0,
                                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                                backgroundColor: ThemeManeger()
                                                        .checkIsDark(context)
                                                    ? tabColor
                                                    : Colors.teal,
                                                radius: 11,
                                                child: Container(
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      border: Border.all(
                                                          color: ThemeManeger()
                                                                  .checkIsDark(
                                                                      context)
                                                              ? Colors.black
                                                              : Colors.white,
                                                          width: 2),
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.circular(
                                                              11)),
                                                  child: Icon(
                                                    Icons.check,
                                                    color: ThemeManeger()
                                                            .checkIsDark(
                                                                context)
                                                        ? Colors.white
                                                        : Colors.black,
                                                    size: 18,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          : const Positioned(child: SizedBox())
                                    ],
                                  )),
                        onTap: () {
                          if (!HomeScreen.selected) {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => ChatScreen(
                                  chatModel: widget.chatModels[index],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            if (ChatPage.selectedIndexList.contains(index)) {
                              setState(() {
                                ChatPage.selectedIndexList.remove(index);
                              });
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                ChatPage.selectedIndexList.add(index);
                              });
                            }
                          }
                          if (ChatPage.selectedIndexList.isEmpty) {
                            setState(() {
                              HomeScreen.selected = false;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        title: Text(
                          contacts![index].displayName!,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                                  ? Colors.white
                                  : Colors.black),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.done_all,
                              color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                                  ? Colors.white70
                                  : Colors.black45,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "سلام",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                                      ? Colors.white70
                                      : Colors.black45),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        trailing: Text(
                          "3:00",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: ThemeManeger().checkIsDark(context)
                                  ? Colors.white70
                                  : Colors.black45,
                              fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advice against using static variable for this.

What you are describing is a clear example of a state-management problem. I recommend you do some research about it, starting by the [Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt).

Then it is up to you which framework or approach to take (Provider, GetX, Redux, Riverpod, ...). I would start by implementing [`ChangeNotifier` and `Provider`](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple), since they are easy to understand and fit perfectly your use case.